# Multiplescreen app for android

Tags: android, sdk, pinch, multiscreen

I would like to create an app that uses 3 screens at the same time. I'm currently using 3 tablets (Samsung Galaxy Tab 10 - Android 4.1). I would like to know if anyone knows an SDK that could help me with the communication of the 3 tablets. I had made some research and found an SDK called Pinch, but It looks like it only works in iOS. By the way, I'm using Android Studio only. Thanks for all the answers, and sorry for bad english.

For example, something like this: [http://imgur.com/onpe5Yd](https://imgur.com/onpe5Yd)